# uninit a pin that I have no reference to

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

```py
def f():
   led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.LED)
f()
```

After I called `f()` pin was initialized, if `led` was a global variable I could simply do `led.uninit()`. But how do I uninit the pin that went out of scope?

Calling `digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.LED).uninit()` gives 'ValueError: LED in use` error.
I know I can just reset the RP2040, but I want to learn how to do this programmatically.